# World coords to screen coords

Tags: coordinates

So I have an exam coming up and I'm having a bit of trouble with one of the study guide questions. Here it is.

Given a world to screen coordinate transform where the rectangle bounded by the points 0,0 and 5,5 in world space needs to be transformed to a screen bounded by the points 0,0 and 100,100. Any coordinate in world space xWorld, yWorld can be converted to screen coordinates xScreen, yScreen by the equations:

```
xScreen = xWorld*xScale + xTranslate

yScreen = yWorld*yScale + yTranslate
```

What are the correct values of xScale, xTranslate, yScale and yTranslate? Assume that positive Y is down in both the screen space and world space.

I feel like it's a pretty simple question, but for some reason I'm just not getting it..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need to linearly map a range of [0,5] to [0,100]. How would you do this? Easy.

Comment: Given that your sample includes a term `+ xTranslate` are you sure that the world x-coordinates are not in the range -5 to +5? If not, your answer might be simpler than you think.